# Is it possible to use VBA to ungroup an EPS picture to create a Microsoft Office drawing object in Word?

Tags: image, vba, ms-word, eps

Ungrouping an EPS picture, converting it to a Microsoft Office drawing object in the process, is possible in PowerPoint as follows:

```
oShp.Ungroup
```

and Excel like this:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup
```

But the closest I can get in Word (with the non-inline shape selected in the document) is this:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Ungroup
```

and this returns the error "Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': Group is locked and cannot be ungrouped".

Yet when I right click on the EPS picture in the document and select Ungroup, I can convert it to a Microsoft Office drawing object and then ungroup it once more to get the individual shapes.

There must be a way to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the shape is a 'Group'

Try this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then shp.Ungroup
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work Siddharth because the shape is of type msoPicture, as it is in Excel and PowerPoint where ungrouping it will convert it to a Microsoft Office drawing object. It appears that Word can't do this!

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood you. You are able to ungroup it?

Comment: It is possible to ungroup it via the Word UI - yes. Programmatic ungrouping appears to be an issue, but only in Word.